# get_item dynamodb with if else condition if item has a match

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

```
def main():
    alias = "jen"
    ddb = boto3.client("dynamodb")

    get_ddb_item = ddb.get_item(TableName="testtable", Key={"employee": {"S": alias}})

    item = get_ddb_item["Item"]
    print(item)

    if item == alias:
         print(f"{alias} is an employee")

    else:
         print(f"{alias} is not an active employee")
```

The only content on the `testtable` is `PK: employee item: "jen"`
I am expecting an out put of `jen is an employee`

This is my code above and it gives me the opposite `jen is not an active employee`
What is the right way of getting the expected output?

Comment: Show us the output of `print(item)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon {'employee': {'S': 'jen'}}

Comment: Ok then, `item` is a dictionary, so `if item == alias` will obviously never be true, because `alias` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this because `item != 'jen'`

```
if item['employee']['S'] == alias:
     print(f"{alias} is an employee")

else:
     print(f"{alias} is not an active employee")
```